# Determine if N is Even

Tags: javascript

I was playing with JS and wanted to create an `isEven(n)` function that returns true if it is even and false otherwise.

Here is what I did:

```
function isEven(n){
  return n % 2 ? false : true;
}

print(isEven(6));
//-> true
print(isEven(-3));
//-> false
```

My question is:

Is this good code? How is JS interpreting this code?

I'm assuming JS returns `true` if `n % 2` equals to `1` and `false` if `0`.

Is this a good solution or would you prefer writting something else like:

```
function isEven(n){
   return (n % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
}    
print(isEven(6));
//-> true
print(isEven(-3));
//-> false
```

Comment: For any number _a_: if _a mod_ 2 is 0, the number is equal.

Comment: This looks like the opposite of code golf! How about throwing an exception from isEven if the argument is not a number?

Comment: @mvds lol! I'm sorry, I just starting with JS and wanted to see if that would be considered okay or if it was better to be more explicit. I understand this code is super simple and probably flawed in many ways. Something may look clever to me but to other more knowledgeable people might look like crap. :P

Comment: @Coal_ What do you mean? I didn't get your observation.

Comment: You stated that _n mod 2_ equals **1** returns true; even though for any number _n_, if _n mod 2_ equals 1, _n_ is **not** even. For example: **[16 % 2 is 0, 16 is even]** and **[17 % 2 is 1, 17 is odd]**

Comment: @Coal_, Jesus! You are right. fixed it! Thanks.

Comment: I think most programmers (with at least a little professional experience) would prefer a clean `a%2` kind of check over a dedicated function doing the same. `isEven()`, `isOdd()`, `isZero()`, `isOne()`, `isNegative()`, where does this end? The intent of `a%2` or `a&1` is quite clear I think, whereas `isEven()` would come as a surprise and would trigger any OCD reader to lookup and check the `isEven()` function to see what magic may be hiding there. Would you expect `isEven("two")` to return `true`? You cannot tell without looking up the source of `isEven()`.

Comment: Another funky example: what should `isEven(4.0001)` return? This depends on your implementation; `a&1?true:false` differs from `a%2?true:false`. Maybe it should throw an exception?

Comment: @mvds, You're are totally right, in this case this function is useless but I'm just starting this book Eloquent JS and it has some examples at the end of each chapter and I was bouncing some ideas on what would be better. Hopefully my next posts will be more _meaty_. Anyways, even with this simple example I learned a lot from you and the other comments. I appreciate the time you took to explain this. I cant wait to start coding a real app!!!

Answer (score 6):

First, a number X is even if X mod 2 is 0.

I think is more understandable something like this:

```
function isEven(n){
  return (n % 2 == 0);
}
```

The function will return `true` if the number `n` is even and `false` if it's odd.

Comment: You're right! I was trying to figure out a clever solution and yours is way better. Would you consider `return !(n % 2);` to be too ambiguous?

Comment: @DanielSegura A function should return 1 for true and 0 for false. So,it's ok if you do that. Always remember that sometimes is better to write more to have and understandable code that writing less and turning the code a little obscure.

Comment: I understand. “Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute” - Abelson & Sussman

Comment: `isEven => n % 2 === 0`.